# MongoDB: How to Subscribe to a Small Subset of a Large Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

In my Meteor app, I have a Mongo Collection on the back-end that has a **large** document that the client wants to subscribe to. This document contains an array of objects that can be upwards of 80,000 items in length. But the client is only interested in the 10 most-recent items from that array.

Here's a sample of the document:

`{
    "_id" : "TfPCCaupse8cgwYeQ",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-03-01T20:42:24.491Z"),
    "type" : "historicalTrades",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "1422161074",
            "price" : 1546.01,
            "amount" : 2.834,
            "tid" : "19009899",
            "type" : "sell"
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "1422161074",
            "price" : 1546.01,
            "amount" : 1.822,
            "tid" : "19009900",
            "type" : "sell"
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "1422161074",
            "price" : 1546.01,
            "amount" : 7.333,
            "tid" : "19009901",
            "type" : "sell"
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "1422161074",
            "price" : 1546.01,
            "amount" : 16.98,
            "tid" : "19009902",
            "type" : "buy"
        },
        ...
        ...
        ...
    ]
}`

Is it possible to subscribe to just the first or last 10 items from that array, without ever loading the other 79,990 into memory (i.e. keep the query super fast)? Or is the better solution to maintain a separate document, in addition to the 80,000 length document, that just contains the most-recent 10 items at any given point in time?

Thanks!

Comment: why not put the data objects into a separate mongo collection and then use limit? It would require a separate pub/sub, but it seems much more logical. Also, if any of the data updates, you have to resend the entire document down the line - if the data were in a separate collection you wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Seems like $slice can handle this on the server. Though I am still concerned if this is trying to load a bunch of data I don't need into memory, just to return the last 10.

```
var subArray = Collection.findOne(
  {type:'historicalTrades'},
  {fields:
    {data: {$slice:10}
  }
}).data;
```